# write a function that returns all of the users names and roles. Don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript

[image]

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Homer',
    role: 'Clerk',
    dob: '12/02/1988',
    admin: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    role: 'Staff',
    dob: '01/30/1965',
    admin: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Marge',
    role: 'Associate',
    dob: '09/10/1980',
    admin: true
  }
]

function namesAndRoles(users) {
  for (var element of users) {
    Name = "Name: " + element.name;
    Role = "\nRole: " + element.role;
    combine = Name + Role + "\n";
  }
  return combine;
}
console.log(namesAndRoles(users))
```

Comment: what you want to be the output here?

Comment: maybe using `=` instead of `+=`?

Comment: declare combine before the loop using `let combine = ""`, then concatenate the strings using `combine +=  Name + Role + "\n";`. (It could be prettier pushing to an array and then `.join("\n")` the values. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you want

```js
const users = [ { name: "Homer", role: "Clerk", dob: "12/02/1988", admin: true, }, { name: "Lisa", role: "Staff", dob: "01/30/1965", admin: true, }, { name: "Marge", role: "Associate", dob: "09/10/1980", admin: true, }, ];

function namesAndRoles(users) {
  combine = "";
  for (var element of users) {
    combine += "Name: " + element.name + " Role: " + element.role + "\n";
  }
  return combine;
}
console.log(namesAndRoles(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning new value instead of accumulate it, store an init value and then concat on every iteration

```
function namesAndRoles(users) {
  var combine = ""
  for (var element of users) {
    Name = "Name: " + element.name
    Role = "\nRole: " + element.role
    combine += Name + Role + "\n"
  }
  return combine
}
```